# Building AOSP from source for a Xperia T3 (D5106)

Tags: android, android-source

So, I have a Xperia T3 (D5106) and wanted to build AOSP from source to it. I took a look at Sony's developer website and found the procedures to build for the T3, but the D5103 model.

Looking at Sony's T3 White Paper, the hardware appears to be the same, with the only exception being the supported broadbands. So I built it, and tried to flash it in my D5106. I got a bootloop.

I have the original TFT file, so I managed to get it back, so no harm done.

My questions are:

1) How can I adapt the source from D5103 to D5106? I don't really care if the 3G/4G doesn't work at all, as long as it boots (it's a Dev Phone, not a personal one, so I pretty much just need WiFi and a few other hardware stuff).
Any links or examples on porting would be deeply appreciated so I can learn which files I should change or what to watch out for.

2) When building, I got an error about clang, and a few other minor stuff, which I fixed all of them, and built again without doing a make clean before. So I don't know if that is what caused the rom to be buggy. Would a clean build for D5103 work on D5106?
Since I got a bootloop I'm being more careful now to avoid doing something irreversible.